# Auto cell editing datagrid using wince in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, windows-ce

I am a beginner using **wince 6.0**, So I just create a datagrid **Products** contains four fields namely:

- Sequence Number
- Product Code
- Quantity
- Radius

I want to edit only **'Quantity'** in its rows, so the user can edit the **'Quantity'** in the **'Products'** data table.

TextBox will appear automatically, if the cell is activated either by clicking or by the arrow keys on the keyboard.

After that ,I input the new quantity in the datagrid component, and once I click ENTER the new value must be saved (without adding an edit button)

Thank u for ur help

Comment: do you have any code to share?

Comment: yes i have one but ,its not complete

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub dg_listArt_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dg_listArt.CurrentCellChanged
        If (dg_listArt.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber = 2) Then
            'Edition traitement


            MsgBox("QTY selected")
        End If
    End Sub
```